# Matrix element and expectation value

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, notation, quantum-states

Can I say that the expectation value of an observable $̂$ for a state $|⟩$: $⟨⟩≡⟨|̂|⟩$ is a more general case of the matrix element$⟨|̂|\beta⟩$? I'm not quite clear how are they related. Also, are there any relationships between $⟨|̂|⟩$, $⟨|⟩$, $|⟨|⟩|^2$ and $⟨|̂|\beta⟩$, $⟨|\beta⟩$, $|⟨|\beta⟩|^2$ ? Particularly, if $|k_{min}⟩$ is a basis state/ground state, and $|E_{j}⟩$ represents eigenvectors of Hamiltonian, then what's the meaning of $|⟨E_j|k_{min}⟩|^2$ ?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I say that the expectation value of an observable $̂$ for a state $|⟩$: $⟨⟩≡⟨|̂|⟩$ is a more general case of the matrix element$⟨|̂|\beta⟩$?

In essence, yes, but some clarifications are in order. The matrix elements of an operator are defined w.r.t. a basis. In principle, a basis ought only to be complete. Thus, one can imagine a basis where $\vert\alpha\rangle$ is a basis vector and thus, $\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \alpha \rangle$ would become a special case of a generic matrix element $\langle \mu \vert A \vert \nu \rangle$ where $\vert\mu\rangle,\vert\nu\rangle$ belong to the set of basis vectors of the said basis. In particular, $\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \alpha \rangle$ would be the $\alpha^{\text{th}}$ diagonal element of the matrix representation of the operator *w.r.t. the said basis*. However, in practice, one chooses an orthonormal complete basis and not just a complete basis. In this context, for $\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \alpha \rangle$ to be considered as an element of the matrix representation of the operator w.r.t. some basis, $\vert \alpha \rangle$ would have to have unit norm.

> Also, are there any relationships between $⟨|̂|⟩$, $⟨|⟩$, $|⟨|⟩|^2$ and $⟨|̂|\beta⟩$, $⟨|\beta⟩$, $|⟨|\beta⟩|^2$?

$\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \beta\rangle $ and $\langle \alpha \vert \beta \rangle $ are not related in any obvious way for the simple reason that the former depends on the operator $A$ whereas the latter is simply the inner product of two vectors. In other words, the latter simply doesn't have any information about the nature of the operator $A$.

One way to look at $\langle \alpha \vert A\vert \beta\rangle$ is as to see it as the inner product of $\vert \alpha\rangle $ and $A\vert\beta\rangle$ where $A\vert\beta\rangle$ is the vector resultant from the action of the operator $A$ on $\vert \beta \rangle$. Since a non-trivial operator non-trivially transforms the vector that it acts on, the resultant vector would be a completely different vector compared to the original vector. In what way the resultant vector would be different than the original vector is precisely what is governed by the operator.

And thus, as one could guess, as to in what way $\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \beta \rangle$ would be different from $\langle \alpha \vert \beta \rangle$ depends on the operator $A$. For example, in the trivial case where you take the operator $A$ to be the identity operator, $\langle \alpha \vert A \vert \beta \rangle = \langle \alpha \vert \hat{\mathcal{I}} \vert \beta \rangle = \langle \alpha \vert \beta \rangle $.

I'm not sure what you mean by the relation between $\langle \alpha \vert \beta \rangle $ and $\vert \langle \alpha \vert \beta \rangle \vert^2$. Certainly, the latter is the modulus-squared of the former.

> [I]f $|k_{min}⟩$ is a basis state/ground state, and $|E_{j}⟩$ represents eigenvectors of Hamiltonian, then what's the meaning of $|⟨E_j|k_{min}⟩|^2$ ?

Since a basis state and a ground state are different things, I am assuming that you meant that $\vert k_{\text{min}}\rangle$ is the ground state and not that it is a generic basis vector (of the basis formed by the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian). In any case, since the ground state of a system is, by definition, the lowest energy eigenstate of the Hamiltonian of the system, its inner product with any of the other eigenstates of the Hamiltonian vanishes (for that Hamiltonian is a Hermitian operator and thus its eigenstates are orthogonal). Physically, $\vert\langle k_{\text{min}}\vert E_j\rangle\vert^2$ would represent the probability that a system prepared in its ground state is found to be in the $j^{\text{th}}$ energy eigenstate upon the measurement of its energy. This probability would be zero unless $\vert E_j \rangle = \vert k_{\text{min}}\rangle$ for the reason given above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!! Could you also explain a bit about what's the physical meaning of $|⟨E_j|O|E_0⟩|^2 $ where $|E_0⟩$ is the ground state and O is an operator?

Comment: @Zhengrong My pleasure. :) $\vert \langle E_j \vert O \vert E_0 \rangle\vert^2$ doesn't have a direct physical significance in general. Formally, $ \langle E_j \vert O \vert E_0 \rangle$ is just the $j0^\text{th}$ matrix element of the operator $O$ in the energy-basis. However, there can be special situations where this matrix element becomes more directly physically relevant. [...]

Comment: [...] For example, if $O$ is the perturbative part of the Hamiltonian (and, say, $E_{0,j}$ are the energy eigenstates of the unperturbed Hamiltonian) then $\vert \langle E_j \vert O \vert E_0 \rangle\vert^2$ has a direct physical significance in determining the transition probability from $0\to j$ (per unit time). See,  [Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule).

Comment: Thanks!! That's really helpful:)